# Change first week of the year to be the first one that starts on monday

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I change the way SQL Server determines the first week of the year?

I'd like to have the first week of the year to be the one that starts with Monday (the first complete week), but I can't find a way to do so on SQL Server.

I tried using `iso_week` but it counts the first week as the first one that contains Thursday:

```
SELECT 
  '2020' [year],
  DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, '2020-01-01') [iso_week],
  53 [expected week number],
  DATENAME(WEEKDAY, CAST('2020-01-01' AS DATETIME)) [week day]

UNION

SELECT 
  '2021' [year],
  DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, '2021-01-01') [iso_week],
  53 [expected week number],
  DATENAME(WEEKDAY, CAST('2021-01-01' AS DATETIME)) [week day]

UNION

SELECT 
  '2022' [year],
  DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, '2022-01-01') [iso_week],
  52 [expected week number],
  DATENAME(WEEKDAY, CAST('2022-01-01' AS DATETIME)) [week day]

UNION

SELECT 
  '2023' [year],
  DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, '2023-01-01') [iso_week],
  52 [expected week number],
  DATENAME(WEEKDAY, CAST('2023-01-01' AS DATETIME)) [week day]

UNION

SELECT 
  '2024' [year],
  DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, '2024-01-01') [iso_week],
  1 [expected week number],
  DATENAME(WEEKDAY, CAST('2024-01-01' AS DATETIME)) [week day]

UNION

SELECT 
  '2025' [year],
  DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, '2025-01-01') [iso_week],
  53 [expected week number],
  DATENAME(WEEKDAY, CAST('2025-01-01' AS DATETIME)) [week day]
```

This is the result, not all years are as I expect them:

[image: Result]

For year 2020 the first week should start on 6th January, same thing for year 2025.

Comment: Use your own calendar table; you should really have one already, if I am honest.

Comment: `WEEK` when used with `DATEPART` is language specific, @Dai, and `01/01/{year}` is *always* week 1.

Comment: The last time I had a problem like this I did week-determination in application code and used normal datetime range queries without using T-SQL's `DATEPART( iso_week` nor 
`DATEPART( week`.

Comment: @Larnu Yeah, I just tested it and deleted my comment when I saw.

Comment: The first Monday of 2019, is 20190107. There are 359 days between 20190107 and 20200101, which is  week 52 for 20200101. How is 53 of 2020 calculated?